# Error when iterating through a parsed CSV, panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

Tags: go

I am trying to do this exercise that takes in a csv of some simple addition question/asnwers and asks the user for a response whilst keeping a score of correct answers.  Each row of the csv is something like, "5+5,10"

However I keep getting this error after the last question is asked and cant seem to figure out where it is happening.

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    ~/main.go:23 +0x260
exit status 2
```

this is my code

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    score := 0

    file := "problems.csv"
    questionSet := parseCsv(file)

    for _, v := range questionSet {
        question := v[0]
        answer := v[1]
        fmt.Println("What is", question)
        ua := userAnswer()
        if validateAnswer(ua, answer) {
            score++
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Your score is", score)
}

func parseCsv(filepath string) [][]string {
    var questions [][]string

    in, err := os.Open(filepath)
    check(err)

    r := csv.NewReader(in)

    for {
        record, err := r.Read()

        questions = append(questions, record)

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        check(err)

    }
    return questions
}

func userAnswer() string {
    var answer string
    fmt.Scan(&answer)
    return answer
}

func validateAnswer(userAnswer string, answer string) bool {
    return userAnswer == answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseCsv` function shall look like below, `append` should be called only if no read error happened

```
func parseCsv(filepath string) [][]string {
        var questions [][]string

        in, err := os.Open(filepath)
        check(err)

        r := csv.NewReader(in)

        for {
                record, err := r.Read()

                if err == io.EOF {
                        break
                }

                check(err)

                questions = append(questions, record)

        }
        return questions
}
```